# MySQL table not accepting data from Flask app

Tags: python, mysql, flask, wsgi

I made a flask application which inserts data into an SQL Database. The application works fine on my laptop but when I transfer it to my home server which has the same Database, the flask app isn't inserting any data and I am not even getting an error. It can read data from the database but it can't insert data into it. The problem isn't in the code, it's probably something related to the server or the SQL database but I don't know what it could be.

```
mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def home():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor() 
    cur.execute(("""INSERT INTO usersdb (name, username, pass, salt)
    VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')""").format("name", "username", "pwd", "salt"))
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: How is it related to html?

Comment: Is your server's database in the same relative directory as in your laptop?
Also, you could surround cur.execute with a try .. except in order to log the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a local flask app, turns out the path to my database was wrong when I moved it to the server! I was storing the database locally on my machine so when I uploaded to server the path was pointing to a local path that did not exist. Check were your path to your DB is pointing incase it is pointing locally.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue because I can get data from the database but cannot insert data into it. And the database actually reacts to me trying to insert the data because it keeps the index of the value I tried to insert so it skips that index when I menually insert the data later

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).